# Deserialize Json case-insensitive

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm working in a ASP MVC4 app, not Web API. I have a c# view model like this:

```
public class Car{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

In client I'm working with knockout.js and the view model is like this:

```
function Car(data){
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
}
```

When I send the knockout viewmodel through ajax to the server:

```
$.post("@Url.Action("MyAction")", ko.toJSON(myCar));
```

MyAction is expecting a Car parameter:

```
public JsonResult MyAction(Car model)
{
...
}
```

But model always have all its properties null, because the post values are lower-case and the Car properties are upper-case.

I'm search for a solution and I find this:

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

But it not work for me, I think is only valid for web API.

Do you know any way to do the json binding case insensitive?

Comment: All the problem was the use of ko.toJSON(myCar), instead I use ko.toJS(myCar) and now it work fine.

Comment: add this to the answers and then make it as answer. this might help many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the problem was the use of ko.toJSON(myCar), instead I use ko.toJS(myCar) and now it work fine.